# GAE Running Python script and GCE permissions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

1. Is some sort of WSGI (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running) necessary for GAE? Is this like HTTPD's CGI configs?
   Ie, in `app.yaml` I have to have `script.app` and reference `app` to a wsgi/webapp object?
2. Trying to use `AppAssertionCredentials` to authenticate from GAE to GCE.
   I've made another script that this snippet worked in:

`credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute')
auth_http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', http=auth_http)`

What I'm trying to do now is create GCE snapshots from GAE using REST API.
I do not understand how to reference the `compute` object for my `POST`, in order to get auth to work (now getting Unauthorized).

This is my script (too many `import`s due to testing):

```
import requests
import urllib2
import logging
import sys
import argparse
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from google.appengine.api import memcache
import datetime
import httplib2
import json
import logging
from pprint import pformat
from apiclient import discovery
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
import cgi
from google.appengine.api import users
import urllib
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import time

PROJECT = "testprojgce"
ZONE = "europe-west1-b"


### OAuth2

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute')
auth_http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', http=auth_http)


# Create snapshot
createsnapurl= "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/"+PROJECT+"/zones/"+ZONE+"/disks/testdisk1/createSnapshot"
req=requests.post(createsnapurl)
```

Comment: Please stick to "one question per question" -- that's VERY fundamental StackOverflow etiquette. Focusing only on question 1, yes: GAE's web server's 2.7 Python runtime connects to your code via your WSGI app(s) (app.yaml can dispatch to one or more of those), just about like any other web server -- any any Python framework of your choice easily makes those (I recommend for your use case a light-weight framework such as falcon, flask, bottle, or webapp2, rather than a rich and heavy full-fledged one such as django or web2py -- but, of course, that's YOUR choice).

Comment: Had doubts whether to open with "This is a 2 part question" or something similar. Sorry for violating SO etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As far as I know, a WSGI object is in fact required since it's how the application communicates to the server environment. This object is easily available using Django, Flask, webapp2, or other frameworks, so it shouldn't be too tough to get. Take a look at:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine

For lots of GAE config samples.

2) Instead of AppAssertion credentials, Application Default Credentials are now recommended.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

It's a lot easier to work with, and seamlessly works on GAE, GCE (assuming you created the instances with the right scopes), MVMs. It also works in your local environment, either using your default "user" account  you get from `gcloud init`, or you can point GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to a JSON Service Account credentials. Locally, I would generally recommend downloading a JSON service account and pointing that environment variable to it since not every API supports the user account.

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
compute_service = discovery.build(
    'compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Note for most APIs you do not need to specify the scopes since it's automatically injected, but if you have missing scope issues, try using the 'credentials.created_scoped' method.

Finally, you almost never need to use something like requests to interact with the REST apis directly, that is the major point of the client libraries. It makes sure your http request is properly authorized and you have language level methods instead of URL strings. Instead, do something like:

```
jsonBody = {
  #see request body section here for how to fill this in     #https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/createSnapshot
} 
compute_service.disks().createSnapshot(project=project, zone=zone, disk=diskName, body=jsonBody)
```

That may not be the exact syntax, leave a comment if you can't get it to work and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Bill, thanks a lot for the thorough reply. Obviously Client Library methods is the preferred way of doing things but I think that for this case they are rather limited (list, add, delete, start, stop - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#nextsteps).  I do not see any `disks` methods. I assume the 'low-level' API (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/createSnapshot) is needed. Please correct me if I am wrong. Or did you mean I do need to use that low-level POST call directly, but just differently?

Comment: @PyGAE, I was running into a similar issue but I'm not sure yet. It might be an issue of the wrong discovery document being pulled down or the wrong API version. It's definitely a problem with the client libraries if you can't make the API calls with them, you should never have to use requests.  I am on Christmas break but I will take another look when I am back.

Comment: I think I found it. Not that straightforward from the API Developers documentation. Here is the `createsnapshot` method (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.disks.html#createSnapshot) and here are the entire `disks` methods and Client Library methods for GCE - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.disks.html.  I'll try that and report back

Comment: Final update: That worked, see previous comment for methods list. Bill, thank you, this is exactly as you said.